# Library linking errors in Linux: symbol lookup error

Tags: linux, opencl, intel

I get the following runtime errors on Linux:

> /opt/intel/opencl-1.2-6.4.0.25/lib64/__ocl_svml_l9.so: error: symbol
>   lookup error: undefined symbol: _ocl_svml_l9_powrf8_half (fatal)

Similar errors occur for:

- _ocl_svml_l9_powrf8
- _ocl_svml_l9_powrf8_half
- _ocl_svml_l9_cvtfptoi32rtesatf4
- _ocl_svml_l9_cvtfptoi32rtenosatf8
- _ocl_svml_l9_cvtfptoi32rtesatf8
- _ocl_svml_l9_powrf1_half
- _ocl_svml_l9_cvtfptoi32rtenosatf1
- _ocl_svml_l9_powrf4_half
- _ocl_svml_l9_cvtfptoi32rtesatf1
- _ocl_svml_l9_powrf4
- _ocl_svml_l9_idiv8
- _ocl_svml_l9_cvtfptou32rtesatf1
- _ocl_svml_l9_cvtfptou32rtesatf4
- _ocl_svml_l9_cvtfptou32rtesatf8

Which **library** should I link with to resolve these errors?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using the Intel OpenCL for CPU (for Core and Xeon).
In this case, you should not link against `__ocl_svml_l9.so`: it is an internal component of the CPU runtime.

You should only link against `libOpenCL.so` by passing `-lOpenCL` option to the linker.